# How to get the indexpath of uitableview section?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a tableview with multiple Sections. but i click on a  tableviewCells row i should get that rows sections

Answer (score 3):

When the user clicks on a cell, a delegate method of ["`tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView%3adidSelectRowAtIndexPath%3a) fires.

To get the row of the selected cell, you can get the indexPath parameter passed in.  Assuming you name that parameter "`indexPath`", getting the row would be as simple as "`indexPath.row`".  You can also get the section via "`indexPath.section`".

Comment: did you set your view controller to be the delegate of the table?

Comment: It's not Michael who should show code.  It's you who should show code so that he or others can find out what's wrong with it.